# Does a predictable process have countably many discontinuities

Tags: limits, measure-theory, stochastic-processes

Suppose $\mathbb{F}$ is a filtration on the complete probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ and the function $V$ is $\mathbb{F}$-predictable. That means that $V$ is measurable w.r.t the sigma algebra generated by the left continuous functions.

I wonder whether this gives the opportunity to state something on the regularity of predictable functions, in particular:

1. Is there a representation/modification of $V$ which consists of left-continuous functions?
2. Can I state, that $V$ has only countable many jumps (either based on the first point or the fact that the sigma algebra is generated by left-continuous functions)?

Comment: I think if V is cadlag (or equivalently caglad) then 2. is true, but I’d need to research it a little.

Comment: @AlexNe Yeah, that result has been discussed a lot and the proof is not that difficult, you can find it on MSE as well :)

Answer (score 0):

The process $V_t=1_{\{0\}}(B_t)$ is optional (hence predictable) with respect to the filtration of the Brownian motion $B$, but $t\mapsto V_t$ is a.s. discontinuous at every point of the (a.s. perfect) set $\mathcal Z:=\{t\ge 0: B_t=0\}$.

Comment: Could you elaborate why this set is not countable? I do get that the $B_t$ hits $0$ "infinity" times, just not how to go on.

Comment: $\mathcal Z$ is a non-empty closed subset of $[0,\infty)$ without isolated points, a.s.  As such it is *perfect*, hence uncountable.

Comment: I do know what a perfect set is. I'm confused about the isolated points. Does this come from the fact that $B$ is not differentiable, which (could) imply that if it hits $0$ at one point, this means that it hits zero at infinitely many points around a certain $t$?

Comment: Consider a rational time $r>0$ with $B_r\not=0$. Let $T:=\inf\{t>r:B_t=0\}$ Then $T\in\mathcal Z$ and $T$ is isolated (in $\mathcal Z$) from the left. By the strong Markov property applied at time $T$, the set $\mathcal Z\cap(T,T+s)$ is non-empty (a.s.) for each rational $s>0$. This means that $T$ is not isolated from the right, hence not isolated, in $\mathcal Z$. This shows that $\mathcal Z$ can't have any isolated points.